# Is there a good way to make vscode intellisense detect g++ gcm files generated from -xc++-system-header flag for importing?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense, c++20, c++-modules

I'm trying to dabble with the c++20 modules feature and would like to import the standard library headers as modules. Currently I have

```
import <iostream>;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "hello world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and I run the commands

```
g++-11 -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -xc++-system-header iostream
g++-11 -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -o program main.cpp
```

This gives a perfectly functioning hello world `program` and a module file at `gcm.cache/usr/include/c++/11/iostream.gcm`. But vscode complains:

> "iostream" is not an importable header

My `c_cpp_properties.json` file is

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++-11",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-clang-x64",
            "cppStandard": "c++20"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Possible solutions that I don't know how to implement:

- A way to tell vscode where this `iostream.gcm` file is
- An alternative way of doing this where the `iostream.gcm` object ends up somewhere vscode already knows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the known IntelliSense [issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/When-importing-a-C20-module-or-header-/1550846).

> When importing C++20 modules or header units in C++ source:
>
> - You may not see IntelliSense completions or colorization.
> - You may see red squiggles that don’t match the compiler.
>
> Status (as of June 2022)

Workaround

```
#if __INTELLISENSE__
#include <iostream>
#else
import <iostream>;
#endif
```

Comment: Has there been a fix? Or is there a workaround that doesn't include touching source code? (If I edit my source code, then version control will track that, which I don't want).

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB If you follow the linked issue, you see the issue is still open and not yet solved.